# Apple Pay interface freezes the page after redirect on mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, browser, stripe-payments, mobile-safari, applepay

We are using Stripe [(Stripe.js / Payment Request Button)](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button) to implement Apple Pay in Safari. All goes according to plan until stripe emits `token` event when we call [ev.complete('success')](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button#complete-payment), which closes the Safari Apple Pay interface.

```
paymentRequest.on('token', async (ev) => {
    if (ev) {
        ev.complete('success');
        let address = await somePromise(),
            fullname = (ev.payerName || '').split(' '),
            customerInfo = ...
            ...

            let params = {...address, ..customerInfo, ...};
            window.location.href = this.resolveRedirectUrl(params); // If we wrap this in setTimeout 1000ms+, issue gets fixes...
            return;
        }
        window.location.href = this.resolveRedirectUrl()
    });
```

It works okay on 12.1.x iOS Safari, but fails on 12.3.x. The Safari Payment interface doesn't leave the screen automatically (does not get dismissed) and when dismissed manually, freezes the whole page to which we redirect. Only upon re-opening Safari the page starts functioning normally.

However if `window.location.href = this.resolveRedirectUrl(params);` is wrapped in `setTimeout` above roughly a second, issue gets fixes. Its like Apple Pay interface doesn't dismiss its UI element correctly if route is changed before it is completely dismissed.

Is there any event that triggers when the interface is completely dismissed? I browsed through the official documentation but to no avail.

`setTimeout` just feels hacky, suboptimal and this approaches mileage may vary based on phone performance, etc...

SO, pls halp! :)

Answer (score 0):

this sounds like more of an issue between Safari, your asynchronous code, and setting `window.location.href` than an issue with Stripe or Apple Pay. `setTimeout` does seem hacky, but there are restrictions inside WebKit that prevent setting `window.location.href` while the Apple Pay sheet is open. Even worse, in testing, it seems you need to give 3-5 seconds to allow everything to "settle" in Safari before the redirect. Something like this should work though:

`setTimeout(() => window.location.href = …, 3000)`

Sorry I don't have a better answer here.